# Linux Arch GNOME Issue

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome

I am running Arch Linux and GNOME

When I go to, Settings->Users, it will not launch the GUI to Add/Edit users? Can anyone help?

It appears to launch for a second and it disappears, it also cloded the settings page itself.

Everything else seems to work fine.

Comment: On Arch, you would use `useradd`...

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around by click on the 'down arrow' at the top right corner of the desktop and clicking on account settings.

This then opens the user manager.